# Understanding the statement of Poincare's Lemma

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading a paper by Marc Yor for my thesis and I came across this lemma

**Poincare's Lemma:** If $\sigma_n $ denote the uniform distribution on $\sqrt{ n}S_{n-1}$ where $S_{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . and if, for $d <n$, $\pi_{d,n}:(x_1,\dots,x_n) \to (x_1,\dots,x_d)$ is the canonical projection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ TO $\mathbb{R}^d$ then for a fixed $d$ s $n \to \infty$, $\pi_{d,n}(\sigma_n)$ converges weakly toward the centered reduced gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}^d$

Can someone please reformulate what the last line of the lemma means exactly?
What I do not understand is how does the projection operator act on a sequence of measures? Do I here need to show that for eacg $f$ which is real vaued, continuous and bounded on $R^d$

$\int f(x) \sigma_n(dx) \to \int f(x) \mu(dx)$ where $\mu$ is the probability distribution of a centered multivariate gaussian on $\mathbb{R}^d$

I haven't had a real course on probability theory so sometimes I have troubles on what might be elementary for most of you. I would be grateful if someone could help me out here. Thanks